# Render multiple templates inside a component template in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I'm trying to build a component which can make a draggle partition between two templates. Kind of like replicating two adjoining resizable frames. I'm thinking that my component will accept two template inputs and then render a div around them as well as a div in between them which acts as the partition slider. Here's what I think the implementation would look like:

```html
<template #frameOne>content of the first template</template>
<template #frameTwo>content of the second template</template>
<split-component [frameOne]="frameOne" [frameTwo]="frameTwo"><split-component>
```

Where the component selector is 'split-component' and the two inputs for the templates are 'frameOne' and 'frameTwo'. I can't find anywhere in the documentation or in any examples how to include a template from outside a component inside of the component template.

Here's my starting component:

```
import { Component, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'split-component',
  templateUrl: './split.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./split.component.scss']
})
export class SplitComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() firstFrame: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() secondFrame: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

And the template for it:

```html
<div class="split">
  <div class="frame1">{{firstFrame}}</div>
  <div class="divider-bar">
    <div class="handle">:::</div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame2">{{secondFrame}}</div>
</div>
```

Of course {{firstFrame}} won't work but is there something else that would?

**UPDATE**

I added this to my component:

```js
@ViewChild("frame1", {read: ViewContainerRef}) frame1: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChild("frame2", {read: ViewContainerRef}) frame2: ViewContainerRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.frame1.createEmbeddedView(this.firstFrame);
  this.frame2.createEmbeddedView(this.secondFrame);
}
```

And changed my template to this:

```html
<div class="split">
  <div class="frame1" #frame1></div>
  <div class="divider-bar">
    <div class="handle">:::</div>
  </div>
  <div class="frame2" #frame2></div>
</div>
```

But it added the content of the template beside the frame div instead of inside...

Comment: i am not quite sure on this but as you mentioned there is no documentation for the same , you can check for dynamic components.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html

Comment: Yeah I must have read over that page maybe 10 times now. The documentation is severely lacking. I think my solution is ok. I ended up wrapping the frames in a div and using those to adjust the size.

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-container` as `ViewContainerRef`?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the question with my solution. There might be a way to do this with the Renderer as well but I've stopped working on it. I'd be interested in a more eligant solution.